# Textual file protect at server

Tags: php, security, .htaccess

I have small php application for internal usage, usually I user mySql database of course but in this case i have textual database, for example dir structure:

```
publichtml/mydatabase

  publichtml/mydatabase/orders
      1.txt
      2.txt

  publichtml/mydatabase/invoice
      1.txt
      2.txt

  publichtml/mydatabase/user
      users.txt
```

How i can protect this database and allow only access from my php source using this function:

```
$dat_example = substr(file_get_contents("mydatabase/orders/1.txt"),0,100000000000);
```

Thanks

Comment: Put it outside your webroot

Comment: Why are you doing a `substr`? And have a look at how htaccess works.

Comment: [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is an option: rewrite direct access to all files in publichtml/mydatabase/*. Personally I prefer the solution from @Anigel , because it is simple and secure.

Comment: @Anigel:

Does i manually create new "webroot" folder? I have this folders on my cPanel host: d.cpanel, .htpasswds, .trash, access-logs, etc, logs, mail, public_ftp, ssl, tmp, www

Comment: No you just put it in a folder that you webserver does not access so put it outside of the public_html folder or whatever your webroot folder is called on cpanel

Answer (score 0):

If you user cPanel hosting just password protect mydatabase folder (Password Protect Directories option).